# Object is not initialized in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, null, adt

I am working on a simple live wallpaper app.

I created a new class to easily create and store some variables.  I initialized the class and when I tried to run its method, it returned null.

Can someone check my code and tell me what is wrong?

```
public int hH;
public int wW;
public Liinijas l;

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,

    l=new Liinijas(100,hH,wW);   /// initializing my object
}
// Now Drawing method that uses my object
void draw() {

            if (l != null) {  
                Log.i("happened?","if happened, isnt null?"); 
                l.step(tx, ty); // this is what I thought, called null pointer exception
                drawLines(l,c,paint);   // main class method that works with variables from Liinijas class. what actually calls exception by trying to access null variables in l

    }   
}
```

Here's the `Liinijas` class, I think the problem is in how I try to initialize these arrays:

```
public class Liinijas {

    public Point[] p,p2;
    public int lielums; 

    Liinijas(int size,int x,int y) {
        p = new Point[size];
        p2 = new Point[size];
        this.lielums = size;


    }

    public void step(int x, int y) {

    }
}
```

SOLVED: 
Problem here isn't that object is null itself, but that its variables were null. Easy to overlook for beginner.
 This solved the issue:

```
public class Liinijas {
public Point[] p,p2;
public int lielums; 
Liinijas(int size,int x,int y){
    p = new Point[size];
    p2 = new Point[size];

    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){    ///relevant new code
        p[i] = new Point();
        p2[i] = new Point();
        }
                      ///irrelevant code follows


        }

public void step(int x, int y){
   }
}
```

Notice the "ugly" way I declare every object in array through for loop.
I'll leave this in case someone finds himself in same unlikely situation :)

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: is that the one from logcat?

Comment: 01-21 02:44:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17806): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 02:44:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17806):  at com.taukulis.interactive_wallpaper.LiveWallpaperService$MyWallpaperEngine.draw(LiveWallpaperService.java:152)

01-21 02:44:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
01-21 02:44:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
01-21 02:44:54.114: E/AndroidRuntime(17806):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: need to get better at this :D

Comment: 1) Add the stack trace to your question. 2) What line is the throwing the error?

Comment: I guess, better question from me would have been, how to do these things, hehe

Answer (score 2):

`Liinijas l;` is getting initialized in the method `onSurfaceChanged` but being used in `draw`.  Maybe `onSurfaceChanged` is not being called before `draw`

Comment: no, if(l!=null) prevents executing before l is initialized. it just never runs.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, error can be reproduced with these two lines:

```
public Liinijas l;
if(l != null){};
```

See what you are doing here? Your variable `l` is declared, but you can't do any operation with it unless it is initialized with some value. You need to initialize it (with an empty object or a `null`, for example).

Comment: Actually, all you have to do is `l = null` and you're good.